# Typescript: concate all the elements in an string array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of string:

```
public scene: Array<string> = ['gittare','saxsophone','drum'];
```

I need to concatenate all the string in the array like `'gittare_saxsophone_drum'` . Here is my solution in recursive way:

```
addressCreator(array:Array<string>){


      if(array.length>0)
           var fileName=array[0]+"_"+this.addressCreator(array); 
      else
          return [];
      return fileName;
  }
```

The none recursive approach could be:

```
addressCreator(array:Array<string>){

      array.splice(0,1);
      for(let e of array)
           var fileName=e+"_"+fileName; 

      return fileName;
  }
```

In both of these solutions, i nused `var` which shouldn't be used in functional programming.

So what is the best approach?

Comment: I cannot see why you are using splice, as splice removes an element from your parameter. This is more of a problem in functional programming as this makes your function a non pure one. After you called your function, your array will be empty and that could have quite some repercussions in other parts of your code

Comment: I suggest you read through the documentation pages on arrays so you know what features and methods are available to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the **join** method for that.

```
let x = scene.join("_");
```